# Plotly Error When Trying to Highlight on Click

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a plotly bar chart that I am rendering in Shiny. When I click on a bar, I would like to highlight it. My current code, however, returns the error: `Error: 'options' must be a fully named list, or have no names (NULL)`.

Code:

```
number_of_debates_from_1803_1910 <- fread("~/projects/hansard-shiny/app-data/introduction/number_of_debates_from_1803_1910.csv")

  number_of_debates_from_1803_1910 %>%
    highlight_key(~decade) %>%
    plot_ly(data=number_of_debates_from_1803_1910, 
          x = ~decade, 
          y = ~no_of_debates, 
          type = 'bar', 
          text = ~paste0("Decade: ", "<b>", decade, "</b>", "\n",
                         "Number of Debates: ", "<b>", no_of_debates, "</b>", "\n"),
          hoverinfo = "text",
          marker = list(color = 'rgb(158,202,225)',
                        line = list(color = 'rgb(8,48,107)',
                                    width = 1.5))) %>% 
    layout(title = paste0("The Hansard Parliamentary Debates", "\n", "Debate Count by Decade: 1803—1910"),
           xaxis = list(title = ""),
           yaxis = list(title = "")) %>%
    highlight(on = "plotly_click", off = "plotly_doubleclick") %>%
    config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Data:

```
decade,no_of_debates
1800,926
1810,2435
1820,2400
1830,7848
1840,7398
1850,8835
1860,10660
1870,14051
1880,31509
1890,31857
1900,49725
1910,5631
```

I find plotly and Shiny errors to be pretty confusing, so help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm dumb. I needed to delete: `data=number_of_debates_from_1803_1910`.